# application canvas page is not loading ,displaying an error message

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-canvas

My application URL http://apps.facebook.com/leaglecases/ was working fine from past 3 months but from last 4 days its canvas page url is not loading instead showing an error message as

> Blockquote

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. 
The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated.
Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
174.123.24.242
4/2/2012 7:08:14 AM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

I am not able to find what went wrong suddenly in the application pls anyone help me out.
and my website doesnot contain any secure URL address only http address complete website.
Below  is the settings i have done is there any mistake in that:

> Blockquote

```
App on Facebook
Canvas URL:   http://174.123.24.242/leagle_fbapp/Home.aspx/

Secure Canvas URL:  https://174.123.24.242/leagle_fbapp/Home.aspx/

Canvas Page:  http://apps.facebook.com/leaglecases
```

Please help me out , i m not finding any way to solve. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your server is probably misconfigured - check your code to make sure there's actually content at /leagle_fbapp/Home.aspx/ on that machine

Comment: @lgy My page http://174.123.24.242/leagle_fbapp/Home.aspx/
is actually working fine in local server.....

Comment: What do your server logs say? Is your server doing user agent detection or mishandling a POST request which you're expecting to be a GET request, etc